# What's a phrase that describes a person who keeps making attempts doomed to fail because they don't want their previous work to have been for nothing?

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-requests, idioms, idiom-requests

What's a phrase that describes a person who keeps making repeated attempts that they *know* are doomed to fail because they don't want all of their previous effort to have been for nothing?

They feel like they can't give up at this point because they've already put so much of their time/money/effort/etc into accomplishing it.

At this point they probably regret having even tried in the first place, but now that they've dug themselves such a deep hole they feel pressured to just keep digging —

— almost as if the hole they've dug is already too deep to climb out of, but they've convinced themselves that if they just keep digging eventually they'll reach the other side and pop out in China or something.

For example:

A gambler who has bet and lost thousands but continues to throw more money away so that the money they have previously bet would not have been for nothing.

Someone who keeps on buying lottery tickets so their previous purchases won't have been a waste if they could just win *one time*.

Someone who tries to build something over and over and over again, and every time it fails — and at this point they've realized that it's probably never going to work but they feel like they can't give up because then all of the time and effort that they have already put into it would have all been for nothing.

To be clear: This person does not *want* or *need* to commit to this course of action — *in fact, it'd be much better for them if they were to stop before they make their situation any worse* — but they feel pressured to keep going anyway, desperately hoping that it will eventually pay off even though they know at this point that it undoubtedly won't.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: The answers to the duplicate question do not mention *chasing losses*, which is is entirely appropriate, especially for the gambler throwing good money after bad.  And another alternative, *sunk costs*, is mentioned only in a comment on that other Q&A.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark  The answers there do not really address the nuances in this question. Here there are elements of denial and desperation and a refusal to accept failure.

Comment: Perhaps a closer duplicate is [What's the name of the continued costly investing {time, effort, money} in something in the hope that that a losing streak must end?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/370487/whats-the-name-of-this-effect/370501#370501)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  OP seems to want a word that describes the person, what's motivating them, not the action. Something like "pot-committed" from that answer, but broader, since gambling is only one example OP gave.

Comment: *He was so **invested** in the approach that he would not -- could not-- entertain the notion of abandoning it.*

Comment: It's throwing good after bad, but IDK what you'd call the person.

Comment: For the reasons already stated by @HighPerformanceMark and TimR, this question is not a duplicate of the earlier ones (although it is related to them), and should therefore be reopened.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Idiom for doing something intentionally despite knowing the outcome might be bad](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/272933/36710)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Is there an English idiom for when you must commit to a course of action even if it turns out to be the wrong one?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/582320/is-there-an-english-idiom-for-when-you-must-commit-to-a-course-of-action-even-if/582335#582335)  The question was closed as duplicate before but it is reopened now. Perhaps, you can explain why it is not a duplicate and why the answers do not fit in other questions. Do you strictly want a word to define the person? An example sentence with a blank might help.

Comment: To *double down* on something? Mostly done by gamblers with a potentially risky bet.

Comment: Colloquial, short, not fully specific to what you want to say: _the person is getting bogged down on things_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Behavioral economics provides us with a laundry list of possible cognitive biases and heuristics underlying *doomed to fail*.

https://thedecisionlab.com/biases

The Sunk Cost Fallacy (already noted) https://thedecisionlab.com/biases/the-sunk-cost-fallacy The Sunk Cost Fallacy describes our tendency to follow through on an endeavor if we have already invested time, effort, or money into it, whether or not the current costs outweigh the benefits.

*Gambler's fallacy* https://thedecisionlab.com/biases/gamblers-fallacy also known as the Monte Carlo fallacy or the fallacy of the maturity of chances, is the incorrect belief that, if a particular event occurs more frequently than normal during the past, it is less likely to happen in the future (or vice versa). *The fallacy is commonly associated with gambling, where it may be believed, for example, that the next dice roll is more than usually likely to be six because there have recently been fewer than the expected number of sixes.*

The Ostrich Effect https://thedecisionlab.com/biases/ostrich-effect The ostrich effect, also known as the ostrich problem, is a cognitive bias that describes how people often avoid negative information, including feedback that could help them monitor their goal progress.

Comment: Although the question contains two examples that involve gambling, it is crucial to both of them that the person keeps gambling so that 'the money they have previously bet would not have been for nothing' or that the previous losses 'won't have been a waste'. That suggests that the fallacy is one of sunk cost, rather than a gambler's fallacy, which involves the mistaken belief that a certain number must be the wining number next time because it hasn't come up recently. The gambler's fallacy does not depend on whether one has actually had any losses oneself.

Answer (score 2):

As has already been pointed out by High Peformance Mark in a comment, the people described in this question commit the fallacy of [**sunk cost**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunk_cost). While the fallacy itself has this well established name, there is no special term for somebody who commits it.

Comment: Actually, I'd rather be associated with the use of *chasing losses*, it's the better choice, grammar wise, to fit OP's requirements.

Answer (score 1):

This [trope](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/IveComeTooFar) is sometimes described with the words:

> "I've Come Too Far..."

The TV Tropes website (linked above) makes the following points:

> In a moment of crisis, a hero or a villain might look back and declare: "I've come too far..." to stop now. This is **a desperate kind of determination**. A common variant on the phrase is, "We haven't come this far just to give up now!"
>
> [...]
>
> This is occasionally a case of the [Sunk Cost Fallacy](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SunkCostFallacy), in which you reason that everything you sacrificed was for nothing unless you sacrifice even more to reach your goal. If you've come so far that reaching your goal requires only a tiny push, it's "more economical", so to speak, to go through with it.

Answer (score -2):

This sounds like Obsessive-compulsive disorder (OCD) is a common, chronic, and long-lasting disorder in which a person has uncontrollable, reoccurring thoughts ("obsessions") and/or behaviors ("compulsions") that he or she feels the urge to repeat over and over.[OCD](https://www.nimh.nih.gov/health/topics/obsessive-compulsive-disorder-ocd#:%7E:text=Obsessive%2Dcompulsive%20disorder%20(OCD),to%20repeat%20over%20and%20over.)

It also sounds like an addiction.
[Addiction](https://newsinhealth.nih.gov/2015/10/biology-addiction)