# Throwing a pot of water out looking at the clouds

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms, idiom-requests, idiom-meaning

> **It  is like  an old  woman throwing   a  pot  of  water out  looking  at the  water  in the clouds**

*The  above  is  an Indian proverb meaning some  innocent  people foolishly  forego  what  is  preserved  for future 
 use   when  they  find  that   something more  useful 
 useful is  likely to be   available  in the near  future which  may not  be  available (leaving  something  at  hand in anticipation  of  something  which  is  likely  to  happen and  of  use  in the  future).*

I would like  to know a  similar  idiom in English.

(I think  it is  not  a  duplicate  as   I searched  for  similar proberbs but  could not  find out. However, if  anybody  finds  out   and  leave  a  comment, I will delete the post instantly)

Comment: You could say this is ["throwing good money after bad"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/186789/etymology-of-throw-good-money-after-bad), which means "squandering what you have while trying to improve a bad situation."

Comment: There is an English saying that has some affinity with this proverb:  "A bird in the hand is worth two in the bush."  Unfortunately, it would not serve the purpose of your proverb, which is a way of passing witty comment on someone's foolish act or proposed act of over-ambition.

Comment: Are they wasting their money, gambling foolishly, or not appreciating what they have? The explanation doesn't give a clear idea of the meaning.

Comment: This has a somewhat different emphasis/focus, but *waste not, want not*.

Comment: Is this the correct interpretation: since one presumes abundance will follow, one might as well squander what one already has?

Comment: Aesop's fable of the dog and its reflection is similar; it has some proverbial summaries although the most common are those already mentioned ("a bird in the hand...", "good money after bad"). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dog_and_Its_Reflection

Comment: @StuartF: Your comment was hidden when I looked at the posted question, so I didn't see that you had suggested the same fable that I cite in my answer. But obviously, I agree with you that it may be on point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Aesop's fable covers much the same idea. Here is how the fable of "[The Dog & His Reflection](http://www.read.gov/aesop/026.html)" is rendered in *The Æsop for Children* (1919):

> A Dog, to whom the butcher had thrown a bone, was hurrying home with his prize as fast as he could go. As he crossed a narrow footbridge, he happened to look down and saw himself reflected in the quiet water as if in a mirror. But the greedy Dog thought he saw a rel Dog carrying a bone much bigger than his own.
>
> If he had stopped to think he would have known better. But instead of thinking, he dropped his bone and sprang at the Dog in the river, only to find himself swimming for dear life to reach the shore. At last he managed to scramble out, and as he stood sadly thinking about the good bone he had lost, he realized what a stupid Dog he had been.

The moral given in the book is "It is very foolish to be greedy," but a more apt moral might be "A bone in the mouth is worth much more than an imagined bone in the river." You could refer to this cautionary tale by saying, "It's like the fable of the dog and his reflection."

Comment: Roger L'Estrange tells the same fable more succinctly, but with a very lengthy "reflexion" on the moral "All covet, all lose," in his book _Fables, of Æsop and Other Eminent Mythologists: With Morals and Reflexions_ (1669), where the fable is titled "[A Dog and a Shadow](https://books.google.com/books?id=KQ1gAAAAcAAJ&dq=%22a+rebuke+to+those%22&q=rebuke+to#v=onepage&q=%22A%20Dog%20and%20a%20Shadow%22&f=false)."

Answer (score 0):

The nearest ones I could think of are:

`Throwing caution to the wind`

Or perhaps even better:

`Betting the bank`

Depending on the feeling of the sentence I would use one or the other, but I think "Bet the bank" has the closest meaning is the sense of squandering riches.

You could even use both together:

`It's like throwing caution to the wind and betting the bank.`